# How to calculate P value in presto database?

Tags: sql, presto, p-value

I have a table like this that captures the experiment data:

| treatment metric values | control metric values |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 6 |
| 5 | 7 |
| ... | ... |

I want to calculate the P value for the experiment in Presto using SQL. I can take average of metric values for both treatment and control groups to compare but I need P-value to see if the results are statistically significant.

Comment: How would you normally calculate it?

Comment: I use python and python packages. But I need to calculate in SQL this time.

Comment: Can you post the expected output?

Comment: The ouput is a single column called pvalue with one value.

Comment: I meant the formula used to calculate it

Answer (score 0):

Given your data format, assuming equal population sizes, all users in the experiment are in the data set, etc:

```
SELECT
   NORMAL_CDF(
     ABS(AVG("treatment metric values") - AVG("control metric values")),
     SQRT(VAR_SAMP("treatment metric values") + VAR_SAMP("control metric values")), 
     0
   ) AS p_value
```